# Joining Oracle table with array parameter

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I need to speed up a procedure that inserts records into a mapping table.

The procedure I am using has the signature:

```
InsertDocsToFolder as
procedure this(p_folderid in number, p_docs in out nocopy DocList)
```

DocList is defined as

```
type DocList is table of int index by integer;
```

The core of the procedure inserts records as follows, t_docs is the main document table and t_mapping is the table mapping p_folderid to p_docs:

```
forall i in 1..p_docs.count save exceptions
  insert into t_mapping select p_folderid, p_docs(i) from t_docs D where D.docid = p_docs(i);
commit;
```

I think I should be able to replace the forall loop with a single SQL statement. Can anyone suggest a faster technique? Since p_docs is a table type can I join it directly to t_docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use collection types created on the server ("create type ...") in SQL.  So if you did this:

```
create type DocList is table of int;
```

then you could select from it like this:

```
insert into t_mapping 
select p_folderid, column_value
from table (cast (t_docs as DocList));
```

Comment: minor update..  I believe you need your last line to be: from table(cast (t_docs as DocList))

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm. Given what you wrote above do you know how to include DocList in an 'execute immediate' statement? I get t_docs is an invalid identifier